# Meteor - how to reactively render arrays instead of cursors (eg. the result of fetch() instead of find() )

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor collection of items, which I need to search/sort/ordering according to rules that are too complex for a MongoDB/minimongo query.

For example, consider a search algorithm that returns results in order of relevance, but runs on the client for speed.

In order to render the items, I call MyCollection.find().fetch(), sort the results and pass them to the template.

This means that any time one of the items in the search results changes, or an item is added/removed, all of the items in the search results are re-rendered.

Is there a way to prevent all items being re-rendered when only one is changed/added/removed?

Comment: What you want to do is probably return a custom cursor in a `Meteor.publish` function that takes the search parameters as arguments. You can also create this cursor on the client, but why would it be faster?

Comment: You can return cursor to template and sort your data by Handlebars helper, I believe this is more proper way

Answer (score 2):

I think if you change your 'MyCollection.find().fetch()' to a meteor.call('methodToFetchMyCollectionInModel'), and make sure you have Meteor.subscribe('MyCollection') in your client, the client is reactive to 'change/add/remove'.